# Apache 2.4 hosting angular not sending all requests

Tags: angular, apache, asynchronous

I am hosting an angular application on Apache HTTPD 2.4.  I am creating a chunked upload process that will send file chunks while a user continues to work on the application.

I have the process working locally with ng serve, but when running it on linux with httpd, the first chunk request goes through, but stops processing after the first.  All network requests show 200 responses.

This is my async method which receives an array of large file parts to post.

```
  async postLargePart(data: any, update_query: any): Promise<any> {
  // Variables
  const proj_id = data[0].filter.id;
    
  // Run update for everything but the large file first
  await this.query.post(this.createFormData(update_query)).toPromise();

  // post the big file in chunks
    for (const dataIdx in data) {
      if (data.hasOwnProperty(dataIdx)) {
        try {
          // get all the current files to append to each big query
          // Need to do this here so that if multiple large files are
          // in the array, it will append the last large file to the next
          const result = await this.query.post({
            action: 'SELECT',
            values: [
              'id'
            ]
          }).toPromise();
          // loop through other files that were posted and append them to the query
          data[dataIdx]['object']['file_set'].push(...result);

          return await this.query.post(this.createFormData(data[dataIdx])).toPromise();
        } catch {
          console.log('Error');
          return null;
        }
      }
    }
```

Here is the call to this method.

```
  ...
  // Split out large and small queries
  return from(this.splitLargeFiles(obj, id).then(result => {

    // store the objects
    const large_file_queries = result.large_file_queries;
    const obj2 = result.obj;

    // Create the query for the smaller files/no files
    const update_query = {
      'action': 'UPDATE',
      'object': (this.serializeDQE(obj2)),
      'filter': {
        'id': id
      }
    };

    // Post the large data
    return from(this.postLargePart(large_file_queries, update_query));
  }));
}
```

It seems that when it is deployed to apache, Angular or Apache (not sure which) kills other future requests in the for loop.  Again, this works locally with NG Serve but will not work correctly with Apache.  We do have MPM installed with Apache but just basic configuration.

Answer (score 1):

The return in the original loop was causing the issue.  I moved the return outside the loop and it fixed the issue.